# $\int xe^{-c|x|}\,dx$ where c is a constant

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

I tried doing integration by parts and saying that $u = x$ and $dv = e^{-c|x|}\,dx$ but then finding $v$ is tricky because of the absolute value of $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Try splitting your problem into two cases: $x<0$ and $x \ge 0$. Solve each case, and see if you can combine the two final answers into one answer. Even if you can't combine them, you will have an answer (even if it is in cases).

I give this answer since this technique can also be used in many other problems.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\frac{d}{dx}|x|=\operatorname{sgn}(x) =\frac{|x|}{x} =\frac{x}{|x|}
$$
and if $dv=e^{-c|x|}$, we have
$$
v = -\frac{|x|}{cx}e^{-c|x|} =-\operatorname{sgn}(x)\frac{1}{c}e^{-c|x|}
$$